# Check if a url with parameter exists in an array

Tags: javascript, regex, url, compare

I have an array with urls that swagger uses, something like:

```
["PATCH /users/{userId}",
"PATCH /users/types/{userIdId}",
"PATCH /products/brands/{brandId}/image",
"PATCH /product-types/{productId}"];
```

I use Mongodb as database and ids are similar, for example, to `userId = "5dce7b7e47224c477734e35d"`. Here is the code inside my function:

```
var havePerm = false;
var myUrl = "PATCH /users/5dce7b7e47224c477734e35d"
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
   // It compares if: "PATCH /users/5dce7b7e47224c477734e35d" equals "PATCH /users/{userId}"
   if (myUrl === urls[i]) { 
      havePerm = true;
   }
}
return havePerm;
```

In this case it should return true, but it returns false.

If the urls don't have a parameter (example: {id}), the comparison is direct, but in the case of PATCH the problem is that I don't know how to compare the parameter between braces {}.

How can I compare those cases? with a regular expression? but I don't know how to build it.

Comment: You want to compare if "myUrl" match one of the patterns? Whatever the mongoId is?

Answer (score 0):

You can break the strings down (method and path components) and then compare the parts, here is an example:

```js
const urls = ["PATCH /users/{userId}",
  "PATCH /users/types/{userIdId}",
  "PATCH /products/brands/{brandId}/image",
  "PATCH /product-types/{productId}"
];

const myUrl = "PATCH /users/5dce7b7e47224c477734e35d";

function parse(str) {
  return str.split(/\s?\//);
}

function isPlaceholder(str) {
  return /\{[^}]+\}/.test(str);
}

function hasPermission() {
  const myUrlParsed = parse(myUrl);
  // check if any of the "urls" elements matches "myUrl"
  return urls.some(url => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(url);
    if (myUrlParsed.length === parsedUrl.length) {
      // check if all the "myUrlParsed" elements match all "parsedUrl" elements at the coresponding index or if the "parsedUrl" element is a placeholder
      return myUrlParsed.every((v, i) => v === parsedUrl[i] || isPlaceholder(parsedUrl[i]));
    }
    return false;
  });
}

console.log("has permission:", hasPermission());
```

What this does is to break every url down to an array that looks like this:

`["PATCH", "users", "{userId}"]`

and then check each of this kinds of arrays agains the array generated from the `myUrl` string.

The check sees if each array element at the corresponding index is equal or if the element is a placeholder (starts with `{` and ends with `}`).

Another way of doing this will be to convert the urls to regular expressions, here is an example:

```js
let urls = ["PATCH /users/{userId}",
  "PATCH /users/types/{userIdId}",
  "PATCH /products/brands/{brandId}/image",
  "PATCH /product-types/{productId}"
];
const myUrl = "PATCH /users/5dce7b7e47224c477734e35d";

function escapeRegex(s) {
  return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

urls = urls.map(url => {
  const regExpStr = url.split(/\{[^\}]+\}/)
    .map(escapeRegex)
    .join('[^\/]+');
  return new RegExp(regExpStr);
});

function hasPermission() {
  return urls.some(url => url.test(myUrl));
}

console.log("Has permission:", hasPermission());
```